# Add a skip parameter to Django CursorPagination

Tags: django

I'm looking to implement in Django 3(.1.7) something equivalent to the [MongoDB cursor.skip() method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/).

What I'm after is an additional query parameter to provide to my [cursor-paginated](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination) REST endpoints in order to skip a given amount of items from the result of the query.

I can't seem to find any example to obtain this result and I'd like not to reimplement the whole pagination class just to add this small addition.

What's the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use slicing on your queryset `page = My model objects.filter(cursorfield__gte=offset)[:page_size]`.

Have a look at the implementation of some pagination classes : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/98e56e0327596db352b35fa3b3dc8355dc9bd030/rest_framework/pagination.py#L395

Comment: Thanks! This thought means the backend needs to put all the items in memory and then discard some of them. Isn’t there a way to offload this to the database instead?

Comment: No, indeed this happens on the database side : the Queryset class implements slicing by adding `LIMIT / OFFSET` in the generated SQL query. https://github.com/django/django/blob/00ea883ef56fb5e092cbe4a6f7ff2e7470886ac4/django/db/models/query.py#L287